# Facebook ad having the app links not opening in app

Tags: android, applinks, android-app-links

I have added meta tags as specified in docs

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="purplle://pruct/1234">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.sample.com">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ShareSample">
<meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

to handle deep links in-app

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="purplle" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I click on the link I am not getting the deep link in the intent of the main activity `getIntent` .